# UIPanGestureRecognizer moves beyond limits

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a waveform that a user can zoom in on, and I have an editing trimmer that I want to expand and pan along with the waveform.

I'm able to get the editing trimmer to expand and pan, but when I pan I have a problem: when the editor reaches the bounds I've set for it, it jolts and moves a little further than it is supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)handleWaveformPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.waveform];


if (self.waveform.zoomStartSamples > 0 && self.waveform.zoomEndSamples < self.waveform.totalSamples) {

    editor.center = CGPointMake(editor.center.x + translation.x, editor.center.y);
    [leftHandle setCenter:CGPointMake(editor.frame.origin.x, editor.center.y)];
    [rightHandle setCenter:CGPointMake((editor.frame.origin.x+editor.frame.size.width), editor.center.y)];
}

[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.waveform];

}
```

The zoomStartSamples are the samples of the waveform unseen at the start of the waveform when the user zooms in, and the zoomEndSamples are the samples unseen at the end of the waveform when the user zooms in. So my constraints are set up such that the editor doesn't move if the user hasn't zoomed in.

Everything works great except when the editor and the waveform reach one of the constraints, and then the editor jolts a little back on the left side and a little forward on the front side. It acts like the editor has a bit of its own momentum.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can provide a video of what the effect looks like? Kind of hard to understand from a textual description.

Answer (score 1):

Because the  editor has its own size. It should move in more constrained "space"

Let's say you have allowed     rect     , in such case allowed x size for the editor's movement will be:

```
{CGRectGetMinX(rect) + editor.size.width*0.5,CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - editor.size.widht*0.5}
```